# why would git status be different in my VM?

Tags: git, virtual-machine

I have a shared folder that is my Rails app. I edit the code in RubyMine in Win7 and run the server in a linux VM. This setup works fine. I've always done all my commits/branching/etc in Win, typically from RubyMine or GitBash.

However, today I did `git status` in GitBash in Win7 and also in the linux vm. The results were dramatically different.

```
# git bash win 7
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

# linux 
~/app> git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#
#   modified:   .dbshell
#   modified:   .gitignore
# etc... 50 more entries...
```

I assumed (incorrectly I suppose) that git status would be coming from a file in the .git directory. It seems like that's not happening, since the files would be the same in both OSs. So:

1. how does `git status` decide what files are in its list?
2. why would `git status` be different in the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for certain how diff decides what files are in the list, but my guess is that it first compares the SHA-1 hashes of the two files; if they're the same, the files haven't changed.  If they're different, it then runs a diff to see if the differences are significant (i.e., it may ignore line-ending issues, etc.).

My guess is that this is a line-ending issue.  On Windows, the diff sees no problem with the CRLF line endings, but in Linux, it flags the files as different.  The Git properties you want to look at is core.whitespace (documentation here: http://progit.org/book/ch7-1.html).  Check to see how it's configured on each OS (`git config -l`).  What you probably want is for it to have the `cr-at-eol` option set.

Comment: Whitespace, ah hah! will check into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue using Ubuntu and working with a Windows 7 in a virtual machine. Following Ethan suggestion, I have solved by configuring core.autocrlf property to true on my Ubuntu with the following command:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```